# Color cycling some elements' css properties with jQuery, :hover gets stuck and erratic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm color cycling through the color, background-color and border-color css properties of some elements with the help of jQuery and [this little plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/).

I'm doing this:

```
var currentColor = myRandNumber; // I get this variable from the main page
var myWebColors = [ '#49aea2', '#5da270', '#a1b144', '#ceb33d', '#ce812d',
'#c44e4e', '#ac4275', '#705f91', '#4d6791', '#5199a4' ];

window.setInterval( animateColor, 2000 ); // not using requestAnimationFrame
                                          // for browser compatibility

function animateColor() {

    $(".new-project-header, .button a:active,
    #logo, ul#menu-main-nav li a:active, ul#menu-main-nav li.contact a,
    ul#menu-main-nav li.contact a:visited, .footer-twitter,
    .footer-mail").animate(
        {
            backgroundColor: myWebColors[currentColor]
        }, "slow");

    $("a:hover, p a:hover, ul#menu-main-nav li.contact a:hover,
    h3.portfolio-item-title a:hover").animate(
        {
            color: myWebColors[currentColor]
        }, "slow");

    $("p a, p a:visited").animate(
        {
            borderColor: myWebColors[currentColor]
        }, "slow");

    if (currentColor == 9) { // the following cycles through the array
                             // in an endless loop
        currentColor = 0;
    } else {
        currentColor++;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gKdEm/2/)!

The problem I'm having is that when I hover over `p a`, while jQuery does the color cycling just fine, but once I mouseout the link will stay at its :hover state, with the latest color it cycled into.

It's even worse when I hover over `ul#menu-main-nav li`. It'll change the a:hover **color**, when that should only be applied to `ul#menu-main-nav li.contact`. It's like this latter selector :hover state is taking precedence over the css of the former.

Maybe I should do everything manually with `on` events? Maybe I should 'reset' all non- :hover states at the end of each loop step? Maybe all of this is overkill and I should try a different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide HTML or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Just updated the post with it, link right below the big code box.

Comment: Aaaand updated jsfiddle, forgot to add the background-color cycling code before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the state back to default when the mouse *exits* the element. I.e. hover completes.

JQuery hover can do this easily.

```
$( "a" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).animate({  color: myWebColors[currentColor] }, "slow");
  }, function() {
        $( this ).animate({  color: default_color }, "slow");
  }
);
```

Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't you use CSS:hover property as explained here  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp  ?

Comment: I do use the :hover property in my plain css in case anything goes wrong / user has no js active. But here I'm color cycling (i.e. you can see the color changing right before you), so I needed javascript for that. The solution you propose is amongst the ones I am thinking of using, but would like to know if there's a better/cleaner one, or if I should try a different approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a loop (`setInterval()`) that is running even if you didn't hover anything. It is useless.

So, i make an update of your [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/synkE/1/) with `setTimeout()`. You can start from something like this. I also replaced `:hover` statments by event handlers. I don't know if it is ok for you. But this is how I should have done it. Hope it'll help.

Comment: Actually, I want the color cycling loop to always be running! So it's not useless, it's vital :) I'm simply modifying the :hover state to keep everything in sync with the main color cycling loop. Still, you're the second person who would do this with events, so I might go that route.

Comment: If it is a random color that you want, simply use Math.floor((Math.random()*11)) each time you hover a link to define what should be the starting color. However, if you have what you were waiting for ;)

Comment: Just curious, have you actually read my code and post? I'm taking the colors from a defined array. The problem resides in the entanglement of the css cascading rules that results from meddling in it with jQuery.

Comment: Don't worry, I read it. But there were other things than could have been optimized to me. But you're right. The original question was only about css and jQuery. All my apologize for trying to help.